# Subir wordpress local de xampp a hosting

Tags: wordpress, hosting

Hola a todos me gustaría subir un portafolio que hice en Wordpress que esta corriendo en Xampp a un Hosting. De que forma puedo hacerlo correctamente? se tiene que hacer con plugins y si es así cual recomendarían? . Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Poco te podemos ayudar aqui con esa pregunta , ya que es demasiado amplia. En google podras encontrar infinidad de tutoriales muy detallados

Answer (score 0):

No, no es nada complicado, lo único es que es muy mecánico. Lo único que tienes que tener en cuenta es que la única diferencia que hay entre local y el hosting es la base de datos donde apunta Wordpress. El resto (estructura, etc) es totalmente igual.

Por lo tanto, los pasos a seguir:

Desconozco si tienes wordpress o no en tu hosting (un wordpress preinstalado de esos que hay hostings que ya ofrecen de salida). Si fuera así, lo único que tienes que hacer es:

1. Modifica el fichero .config para que apunte a los datos que hay en tu hosting y lo subes a tu hosting.
2. Si no tienes el template/plantilla instalado, instalalo igual que lo has hecho en local.
3. Subes el contenido de la carpeta wp-content\uploads (es donde están las imágenes de la galería, etc) y wp-content\plugins (donde están los plugins) para que sean los mismos que tienes en local. Los plugins se pondrán pero no se activarán, deberás entrar al panel de control y activarlos manualmente.

Y si no tienes wordpress preinstalado, el proceso es el mismo salvo que el punto 1 tienes que instalarlo tu después de

1. Sube todo el contenido de la carpeta de tu proyecto de Wordpress (C:\Xampp\Htdocs\NombreProyecto) a tu hosting.
2. Modifica el fichero .config para que apunte a los datos que hay en tu hosting.
3. Instala Wordpress y pon el template/plantilla que quieres utilizar.
4. Una vez instalado actualiza la página y debería verse todo.